# Sitecore8: locked pages cannot be unlocked by other user

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Currently if a user has locked some sitecore item and forget to unlock that item,There is no way to unlock the item by other user except for administrator. I want that some user should have permission to unlock the item that locked by others. Is this thing possible in Sitecore 8?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one : [allow users to unlock items locked to others in Sitecore](http://www.sitecore.net/nl-be/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/02/allow-users-to-unlock-items-locked-to-others-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx) (I if have not test it with Sitecore 8 but likely that works)

Another way is automatically unlocked when the session has expired. [Lock Pick Module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Lock_Pick.aspx)

More about unlocking see: [Sitecore Locked items](https://translate.google.nl/translate?sl=nl&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=nl&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsitecore.stockpick.nl%2Fnederlands%2Flocked-items%2F&edit-text=&act=url)

Comment: @ Jan In experience editor we have unlock button, Which is active only for admin and for the user who locked it. Is there any way so that unlock button in experience editor is active for some other users also?

Comment: The code from "Allow Users to Unlock.." does. (if I remember correctly, I used it in Sitecore 6.5)  it patch / overwrites the existing functionality. if not it is easy to make such a button,